# How to show that the following is satisfied for all vector space axiom?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

Let $V=\{a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0|a_1, a_2, a_3\in \mathbb{R}, a_2\ne 0\}$ with operation defined by $$(a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)+(b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0)=(a_2+b_2)x^2+(a_1+b_1)x+(a_0+b_0)$$

$$c(a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)=ca_2x^2+ca_1x+ca_0$$

Here I am wondering if the identity is $(0x^2+0x+0)$ and the additive inverse is $-(a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)$.

For other axioms, I don't see any that is not satisfied, could someone point out?

Comment: That's all right

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is defined the way you say with the constraint on $a_2$, how can $(0x^2+0x+0)$ be an element of $V$?

So it is not a vector space.

If you eliminate the constraint $a_2 \ne 0$ then you get a vector space: it is the space of polinomials of degree less than or equal to 2.

Comment: In formal statement: because there exists no $b_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_2+b_2=a_2$, the identity axiom is not satisfied. Is it correct?

Comment: I did not catch the point. Can you explain?

Comment: So we are showing that there exists no identity element for this operation and therefore it is not a vector space. Right?

Comment: That is correct. The identity element does not exist and so $V$ is not a vector space. So maybe in your first comment you would mean "there exists no $b \in V$ such that $a+b=a$ with $a \in V$".

Comment: But since $a_2$ is declared as from $\mathbb{R}$, shouldn't $b_2$ be from the same place?

Comment: 1) You need to find the identity of $V$ not that of $\mathbb{R}$. 

2) $a_2$ is not from $\mathbb{R}$ but from $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, per your definition of $V$. So maybe you would mean "there exists no $b_2 \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ such that $a_2+b_2=a_2$". Then there exists no $b \in V$ such that $a+b=a$, where $a \in V$.